# Spring mongo db configuration for unit test

Tags: spring, mongodb, unit-testing, spring-mvc

I try to use fongo for unit test, and I add another mongo configuration inside test to replace the original one but it's not working.

I followed some tutorials to use

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
```

these two annotation for test class and I tried it, it failed with bean creations errors as follow:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.class]
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling
```

Here's my test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Controller.class)
public class ApplicationTests {
  @Autowired
  private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
  }

  ... Tests here ...

  @After
  public void tearDown() throws Exception {
  }

  @Configuration
  @EnableMongoRepositories
  @ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = { RecorderRepository.class })
  static class MongoConfiguration extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
      return "test-db";
    }

    @Override
    public Mongo mongo() {
      return new Fongo("test").getMongo();
    }

    @Override
    protected String getMappingBasePackage() {
      return "com.mongo.test";
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using spring-data-mongodb:1.7.2.RELEASE and accessing db by calling mongoOperation in my application instead of autowired a repository. Like this

```
private AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context =
    new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MongoConfig.class);
private MongoOperations mongoOperation =
    (MongoOperations) context.getBean("mongoTemplate");
```

Is it the reason why

```
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = { RecorderRepository.class })
```

not working?

How should I do to make it works? I will be grateful for any help you can provide.

=============================================================

Update:

I tried embedded mongodb, still got the problem that unavailable connect to database. Do I need to setup anything else? Or add annotation?

Here's my configuration:

```
static class MongoConfiguration extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {
  private MongodStarter starter = MongodStarter.getDefaultInstance();

  @Override
  public Mongo mongo() throws Exception {
    return new MongoClient("localhost", 12345);
  }

  @Bean(destroyMethod = "stop")
  public MongodProcess mongod() throws IOException {
    return mongodExe().start();
  }

  @Bean(destroyMethod = "stop")
  public MongodExecutable mongodExe() throws IOException {
    return starter.prepare(mongodConfig());
  }

  @Bean
  public IMongodConfig mongodConfig() throws IOException {
    return new MongodConfigBuilder().version(Version.Main.PRODUCTION)
                                    .net(new Net(12345,Network.localhostIsIPv6()))
                                    .build();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Fongo.  I have done this with [Embedded Mongo](https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo) though.

```
import com.mongodb.Mongo;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientOptions;
import de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.MongodExecutable;
import de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.MongodProcess;
import de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.MongodStarter;
import de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.config.IMongodConfig;
import de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.config.MongodConfigBuilder;
import de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.config.Net;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import java.io.IOException;

import static de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.distribution.Version.Main.PRODUCTION;

/**
 * Embedded MongoDB configuration for testing.
 *
 * @author Ken Blair
 */
@Configuration
public class EmbeddedMongoConfig {

    @Autowired
    private MongoProperties properties;

    @Autowired(required = false)
    private MongoClientOptions options;

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    public Mongo mongo() throws IOException {
        final Net net = mongod().getConfig().net();
        properties.setHost(net.getServerAddress().getHostName());
        properties.setPort(net.getPort());
        return properties.createMongoClient(options);
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "stop")
    public MongodProcess mongod() throws IOException {
        return mongodExe().start();
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "stop")
    public MongodExecutable mongodExe() throws IOException {
        return MongodStarter.getDefaultInstance().prepare(mongodConfig());
    }

    @Bean
    public IMongodConfig mongodConfig() throws IOException {
        return new MongodConfigBuilder().version(PRODUCTION).build();
    }
}
```

This is intended for use with Spring Boot.  Embedded Mongo is started and `MongoProperties` is setup to connect to the embedded instance.  If you're not using Spring Boot then instead of update `MongoProperties` you'll want to update whatever configuration is responsible for the mongo connection.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, I'll try it later. Do I need to add or adjust any annotation in test class?

Comment: I updated the question with new configuration. Do you have any idea to make it works? Thanks!